# Rows are not posting back in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In the project there are two models as below

```
public partial class provider_preapproval
{
public string encounter_type { get; set; }
public DateTime? e_start_date { get; set; }
public DateTime? e_end_date { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("preapproval")]
public virtual IList<provider_service_dtls> provider_service_dtls { get; set; }
}

 public partial class provider_service_dtls
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long service_id { get; set; }
        public long preapproval_id { get; set; }
        public string activity_code_type { get; set; }
        public string activity_type { get; set; }
        public string activity_type_name { get; set; }
        public string activity_code { get; set; }
        public string activity_name { get; set; }
        public string internal_activity_code { get; set; }
        public string internal_activity_name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? activity_start_date { get; set; }
        public decimal? net_amt { get; set; }
        public decimal? unit_amt { get; set; }
        public decimal? quantity { get; set; }
        public string clinician { get; set; }
        public string clinician_code { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("preapproval_id"), InverseProperty("provider_service_dtls")]
        public virtual provider_preapproval preapproval { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**The view cshtml**

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Preapprove", "Preapproval", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form1", id = "form1", enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "field-validation-error text-danger" })
 //template to generate dynamic rows  
<table id="Newservice" style="display:none">
 <tr>
<td><select  style="width:100px" class="code_type" name="provider_service_dtls[#].activity_code_type" value></select> </td>
<td><select  style="width:100px" class="act_type" name="provider_service_dtls[#].activity_type" value></select> </td>
<td><input  class="act_name" style="width:150px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].activity_name"  value /></td>
<td><input  class="clini" style="width:150px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].clinician" value /></td>
<td><input  class="" style="width:40px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].unit_amt" value /></td>
<td><input  class="" style="width:25px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].quantity" value="1"/></td>
<td><input  class="" style="width:40px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].net_amt" readonly value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="provider_service_dtls.Index" value="%" />
</td>
<td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
</tr>
</table>
//template ends here
<table id="service" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
 <tbody>
@if (Model != null)
{
for (int i = 0; i < Model.provider_service_dtls.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
 <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_code_type, (SelectList)@ViewBag.activity_code_type, "--- Select Activity Code Type ---", new { @class = "m-wrap" })</td>
 <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_type, (SelectList)@ViewBag.activity_type, "--- Select Activity Type ---", new { @class = "m-wrap" })</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_name)</td>                                                
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].clinician)</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].unit_amt)</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].quantity)</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].net_amt)
<input type="hidden" name="provider_service_dtls.Index" value="@i" />
 </td>
<td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
 </tr>
 }
 }
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
//row for showing total of quantity and net_amt
<tr id="totals">
<td></td>
<td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
<td>Total</td>
<td style="text-align:right">0</td>
 <td style="text-align:right">0</td>
<td></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
 }
```

after filling the form and click submit this is submitting successfully and value to provider_service_dtls is posting back as shown below

[image]

Now i added a jquery method to find out total and net_amt by multiplying quantity and unity amount

**Jquery**

```
var body = $('#service').children('tbody').first();
var totals = $('#totals');
 body.on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
var value1 = cells.eq(4).find('input').val();
var value2 = cells.eq(5).find('input').val();
var value3 = new Number(value1) * new Number(value2)
cells.eq(6).find('input').val(value3.toFixed(2));
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
// get the column
var columnIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
 var rows = body.find('tr');
 $.each(rows, function () {
var amount = $(this).children('td').eq(columnIndex).children('input[type="text"]').val();
total += new Number(amount);
     });
totals.children('td').eq(columnIndex).text(total);
    });
```

After adding this Jquery the `total` and `net_amt` is calculating successfully when a change in `service table columns` are happening but the `provider_service_dtls` are posting back with null value as shown below

[image]

Now i found out the issue 
the line

```
cells.eq(6).find('input').val(value3.toFixed(2));
```

is making this..if i comment this line and submit the `provider_service_dtls` will have values while posting back

I tried with

```
cells.eq(6).text(new Number(value1) * new Number(value2));
```

here also value is not posting back

I am not understanding why it is not posting back value for `provider_service_dtls` to controller when this line is there in the jquery.

Please help to sort this out

Comment: Watch the POST with the browser's network monitor. The request body will show you exactly what is being sent to your controller action before any binding takes place.

Comment: Open the browser's developer console (usually F12). Then select the network tab. Often you will need to press the "start recording" button. You might see a "Preserve Log" option -- you'll want that on too. Then make your form submission. Watch for the POST to `Preapproval/Preapprove`. You can click on this line in the console and it will show you network request/response headers and body. These are often very helpful in debugging client-to-server problems like this.

Comment: @jasen it is not showing the POST method

Comment: @jasen thanks for the help..i found the issue through console :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue

```
cells.eq(6).find('input').val(value3.toFixed(2));
```

This line in the script will change the value of type `'input'` in cells (6) as value of value3.

Inside the cell 6 there are two  input type `1.input type text for net_amt`
and `2. input type hidden i for the index`.

So the above jquerys tatement will change both input type value to the value3. So the index will mismatch with the index of dynamically created rows.Hence while posting it cannot identify the rows to post back with index values.

so I changed the  script to

```
cells.eq(6).find('input[type="text"]').val(value3.toFixed(2));
```

so this will only change the value of  input type text for net_amt. The value of input type hidden `i` will remain same.

thanks @jasen for your comment. The inspect element help to find this issue.